# Default dialer permission dialog automatically returns RESULT_CANCELLED without showing permission dialog in Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement default dialer app.  My code is working fine in below android 13 and same is not working in 13 (api level 33)

- targetSdkVersion = 33
- compileSdkVersion = 33
- minSdkVersion = 24

Below code is working in in api level < 33. But in android 33 it is not showing permission dialog.

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```

```
    private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("TAG", "RESULT_OK")
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "cancelled")
        }



private fun setPhoneDefault() {
        if (getSystemService(TelecomManager::class.java).defaultDialerPackage != packageName) {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    val rm: RoleManager = getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE) as RoleManager
                    if (rm.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER) && !rm.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)) {
                        val intent = rm.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)
                        startForResult.launch(intent)
                    }
                } else {
                    startForResult.launch(Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER).apply {
                        putExtra(
                            TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME,
                            packageName
                        )
                    })
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```